# XPATH - how to select this part of the text?

Tags: php, xpath

Code on page:

```
<div class='container'> 
<p>
    <b>Address:</b> Some address<br />
    <b>Phone:</b> phone1, phone2<br />
    <b>E-mail: </b><a href='mailto:somemail' >somemail</a><br />
    <b>Site:</b><a href='somesite'>somesite</a>
</p>    
</div>
```

I need to select text after `</b>` and before `<br />` using XPATH.
In this case I would need to get 'Some address' or  'phone1, phone2' etc.

'Some address' needs to be in $var1
'phone1, phone2' in $var2

I tried with `.//*[@class="container"]/p/text()[1]` it didn't worked.

Comment: do you also want to get somemail and somesite? because technically they are not between b and br.

Comment: yes, i want to select them also, and put them in different variables

Comment: You can use FireBug to see the xpath of an element in the bar at the top of the HTML pane.

Comment: Yes I know that, but with it I cannot select data I need.

Comment: @Matt Using Firebug is only of limited use. First of all it only gives you direct paths to single element and second (and more important) it will operate on the DOM in the browser, which is not necessarily identical to the markup from the source because browser will add any implied markup. This is often a source for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
/div[@class="container"]/p/descendant-or-self::text()[
    not(ancestor::b) 
    and normalize-space(.) != ""
]
```

This will select the text nodes within the P element tree (of the div with the class attribute "container") that are not within a B element tree or empty, e.g. this would give you

- "Some address",
- "phone1, phone2",
- "somemail" and
- "somesite".

[Demo](http://codepad.org/PmrMtHWX)

Also have a look at this [XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Comment: YEY! You didn't have to make demo for me :) Now I have problem with putting values in array http://codepad.org/Li1B2br7

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can reach is :

```
'//div[@class="container"]/p/text()[preceding::b[contains(text(),"Address")] and following-sibling::b[contains(text(),"Phone")]]'
```

OR as @Gordon suggested

```
 '//div[@class="container"]/p/text()[following::b[contains(text(),"Phone")] and normalize-space(.)!=""]'
```

:)